# issue with multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am working on android app and I made the layout of the app suitable for my device galaxy note 2, and when I tried the app on my device it was perfect but when I added another layout folder for normal screen size and then tried it on my device it shows the normal layout which its not suitable for large screen like galaxy note 2.

the only way to make the app display the first suitable layout that I made is by removing the normal layout folder, but I need to add normal , large and small layout folders to make the app works in different screen devices.

when I try the app first it looks perfect my phone like this:

and when I add normal layout folders it looks like this on my phone:

Comment: Check this link http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: Paste a screenshot of your layout structure. Expand all layout folders

Comment: I added how the app looks on my device after adding normal layout folder.

Comment: If it is possible for you to target only devices with Android 3+, use swXXdp directories. Your galaxy Note is probably reporting itself as normal device. This old division is pretty inacurate. Best solution would be not using any hardcoded dimension values, just use wrap content, match parent, paddings margings and centering and you will get universal ui.

Comment: @snapix  thanks man, you are right galaxy note 2 considered as normal  screen.